# Magento 2 Configured Varnish after check X-Magento-Cache-Debug show Miss?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, varnish, magento2.4.5, magento2.4.6

i have configured varnish in magento 2.4.5. i am getting **varnishlog** command X-Magento-Cache-Debug: MISS. currently i am using apache server.

I have configure varnish in Magento 2.4.5. Backend configured as per the below Screenshot.
https://i.imgur.com/j0Oj2UL.png

but in frontend not show "X-Magento-Cache-Debug:MISS/HIT".

https://i.imgur.com/6QMBU1o.png

i have checked in server log using the below command.i am getting the below response and get

X-Magento-Cache-Debug : MISS

**sudo varnishlog**

> ```
> *   << Request  >> 66232
> -   Begin          req 66231 rxreq
> -   Timestamp      Start: 1685699104.524062 0.000000 0.000000
> -   Timestamp      Req: 1685699104.524062 0.000000 0.000000
> -   VCL_use        boot
> -   ReqStart       127.0.0.1 51720 a0
> -   ReqMethod      GET
> -   ReqURL         /health_check.php
> -   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1
> -   ReqHeader      Host: localhost
> -   ReqHeader      Connection: close
> -   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.1
> -   VCL_call       RECV
> -   VCL_return     pass
> -   VCL_call       HASH
> -   VCL_return     lookup
> -   VCL_call       PASS
> -   VCL_return     fetch
> -   Link           bereq 66233 pass
> -   Timestamp      Fetch: 1685699104.524305 0.000242 0.000242
> -   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
> -   RespStatus     503
> -   RespReason     Backend fetch failed
> -   RespHeader     Date: Fri, 02 Jun 2023 09:45:04 GMT
> -   RespHeader     Server: Varnish
> -   RespHeader     content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
> -   RespHeader     Retry-After: 5
> -   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 66232
> -   RespHeader     Age: 0
> -   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.6)
> -   VCL_call       DELIVER
> -   RespHeader     **X-Magento-Cache-Debug: MISS**
> -   RespHeader     Pragma: no-cache
> -   RespHeader     Expires: -1
> -   RespHeader     Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
> -   RespUnset      Age: 0
> -   RespUnset      Server: Varnish
> -   RespUnset      X-Varnish: 66232
> -   RespUnset      Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.6)
> -   VCL_return     deliver
> -   Timestamp      Process: 1685699104.524348 0.000285 0.000043
> -   Filters
> -   RespHeader     Content-Length: 282
> -   RespHeader     Connection: close
> -   Timestamp      Resp: 1685699104.524431 0.000368 0.000082
> -   ReqAcct        70 0 70 293 282 575
> -   End
> ```

I have debug it `/etc/varnish/default.vcl` file and check "sub vcl_deliver". if condition resp.http.x-varnish not true that's why it will not Hit Varnish.

```
sub vcl_deliver {
    
    if (resp.http.x-varnish ~ " ") {
        set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "HIT";
        set resp.http.Grace = req.http.grace;
    } else {
        set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "MISS";
    }

    # Not letting browser to cache non-static files.
    if (resp.http.Cache-Control !~ "private" && req.url !~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
        set resp.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
        set resp.http.Expires = "-1";
        set resp.http.Cache-Control = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0";
    }

    if (!resp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        unset resp.http.Age;
    }
    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Debug;
    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Tags;
    unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;
    unset resp.http.Server;
    unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
    unset resp.http.Via;
    unset resp.http.Link;
}
```

we have configured Port on varnish.service file as per the below screenshot.

File Path : /etc/varnish/default.vcl

https://i.imgur.com/SdJ5Yeg.png

File Path : /etc/systemd/system/varnish.service

https://i.imgur.com/kasjhbh.png

i have run server the below command i am getting the below o/p in terminal.

**sudo varnishlog -g raw -i backend_health**

```
0 Backend_health - default Still sick -------- 0 5 10 0.000000 0.000000 "Open error 110 (Connection timed out)"
         0 Backend_health - default Still sick -------- 0 5 10 0.000000 0.000000 "Open error 110 (Connection timed out)"
         0 Backend_health - default Still sick -------- 0 5 10 0.000000 0.000000 "Open error 110 (Connection timed out)"
         0 Backend_health - default Still sick -------- 0 5 10 0.000000 0.000000 "Open error 110 (Connection timed out)"
         0 Backend_health - default Still sick -------- 0 5 10 0.000000 0.000000 "Open error 110 (Connection timed out)"
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your health check is the only item in the logs probably means that regular requests aren't being sent to Varnish.

While `varnishlog` output in general is very useful, your log output didn't contain a lot of debuggable information.

If Varnish is not receiving any of the requests, we should look at how Varnish is configured. I advise you to add your systemd settings for the `varnishd.service` file, this will show in which IP/port `varnishd` is listening. It might explain why you're not seeing the logs in `varnishlog` and why the debug header is missing.

Let's start with that and work our way forward.

### Update

The root cause of the problem is as expected: Varnish is not listening on port `80`.

Your `varnish.service` file has `varnishd` listening in port `8080`.

Here's the solution:

- Stop `varnishd` and reconfigure `varnish.service` to listen on port `80` by setting `-a :80`
- Stop your web server and make it listen on port `8080`
- Run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` to make sure systemd is aware of the configure changes
- Restart varnish by running `sudo systemctl restart varnish`
- Restart your web server
- Alter your Magento configuration for Varnish and set the backend on port `8080` if that is not the case

Comment: I have added varnish.service file and default.vcl file screenshot.please check